# Insert icon into SVG rectangle with CSS only

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Is there a way to insert an icon (PNG or SVG format) at the corner of a `<rect>` from a SVG file ?
Or do I have to create an `<image>` element and insert it at the appropriate place in my SVG file using javascript ?

For example, in my SVG I have several `<rect>` whose I set the `app` class using javascript :

```
// before my js manipulation
<rect x="0" y="1597.18" width="113.386" height="86.5984" class="st56"/>

 /*
 ** After my js manipulation this line would become :
 ** <rect x="0" y="1597.18" width="113.386" height="86.5984" class="st56 app"/>
 */
```

And now some CSS :

```
.app:not(:hover) {
    stroke: #ff0000;
    stroke-width: 2;
    /*
    ** Can we add something here in order to add an image into the corner of the rect
    ** (.app is always a rect)
    */
}
```

By the way, here, if I just use `.app` instead of `.app:not(:hover)`, it's not working. Any idea why ? (I also have css properties for `.appContainer:hover .app` and `.appContainer:hover`.)

Comment: CSS can only style what's there. I really don't understand what you are trying to do. It certainly can't add actual code to an SVG.

Comment: It can't, but CSS can insert image into a page or as an element background using `url()`and more. I was looking for something like that to apply to my rect for the appropriate effect I'm looking for.

Comment: Apparently not - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736946/how-to-set-a-svg-rect-elements-background-image